# Rotate <a> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to rotate a simple `<a>`-element with jquery:

```
 <a href="#" id="optbut2" style="margin-right: 8px;">
```

This element is located inside a list:

```
 <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" id="optbut2" style="margin-right: 8px;">V</a><a href="#">Motorola</a></li>
```

Since im using Chrome i tried:

```
$('#optbut2').css('-webkit-transform','rotate(20deg)');
```

But somehow it wont work! What do i wrong? Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6059/

Comment: Is there a reason that this needs to be done in JavaScript?
Also, jQuery automatically adds the appropriate vendor prefixes so the `-webkit-` part is not necessary.

Comment: Due to the anchor tag is display inline by default

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can't be an inline display element.

```
$('#optbut2').css({
    'display' : 'inline-block',
    '-webkit-transform':'rotate(20deg)'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6060/

Comment: @AlienWebguy But look at all those bytes you could save!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @AlienWebguy's response, I would also suggest changing the Javascript to this:

```
$('#optbut1').css({'display' : 'inline-block',
                 '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(20deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate(20deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate(20deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate(20deg)'});

$('#optbut2').css({'display' : 'inline-block',
                 '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(20deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate(20deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate(20deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate(20deg)'});
```

That way you'll have better cross-browser support.

Answer (score 0):

APAD1 and AlienWebguy both provided working solutions. However, unless the rotation is dynamic or custom per element, I would highly recommend doing it by adding/removing a class rather than adding inline styles. Cleaner code and keeps the CSS where it belongs; in the .css. You also do not need the -ms and -o prefixes (http://css3please.com/)

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6064/

JS

```
$('#optbut1').addClass("rotate");
```

CSS

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    display: inline-block;
}
```